# URL Rewriting and Redirecting with folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I know there are lots of question on htaccess, yet I tried the different code I could find on Google and StackOverFlow, none worked.

I have the following in my root :

```
index.php
.htaccess (the one I am trying to write)
controllers
    --index.php
    --mycontroller.php
models
    --mymodel.php
view
    -index.php
    --myview.php
```

(I am working on localhost with MAMP&Firefox)

What I have is this link

```
localhost:8888/MySite/controllers/mycontroller.php
```

What I want is

```
localhost:8888/MySite/mycontroller
```

And when I manually enter the url, I would like it to be redirected to the right controller in my MVC code

I tried this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /controllers/$1 [L]
```

It doesn't redirect when I go to blabla/controllers/mycontroller.php and doesn't understand what I am asking when I manual go to blabla/mycontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this to make it work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MySite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ controllers/$0.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your base is in `/MySite/` then it needs to reflect the `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MySite/

# match against the php filename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Mysite/(.*)$

# check to see if the request, routed through controllers actually points to an existing file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/MySite/controllers/%1.php -f

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controllers/$1.php [L]
```

This should take a request for the URI: `/MySite/foo` and rewrite it to `/MySite/controllers/foo.php` *if there's a `foo.php` file in the controllers directory*.

Comment: I tried your code and requested /MySite/foo, but it doesn't work (I have a foo file in my controller). And when I do /MySite/controllers/foo, it works (of course), but doesn't rewrite to /MySite/foo ... What can be off ? Btw, how can I see if my .htaccess is really being read through and not ignore ?

Comment: @BabyAzerty You can try adding a `RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [L,R]` to see if any request goes to google. Edited my answer, realized that you needed to pull out the last path node from `%{REQUEST_URI}`.